# facebook bot Failed to fetch the file from the url

Tags: botframework

My facebook bot has 2200 subscriber , so I am using the below code to send them an image daily . However , this code is failing for most of the users with the error as captured from bot framework

```
 public static class MessagesSender
{
    public static void SendSpecificMessage(string botName, string serviceURL, string botId, string messageCode, string messageText, string imageURL, Customer customer , Guid logId)
    { 
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceURL)); 

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => SendMessage(botName, serviceURL, botId, messageCode, messageText, imageURL, customer, connector , logId));
        thread.Start(); 

    }

    private static void SendMessage(string botName, string serviceURL, string botId, string messageCode, string messageText, string imageURL, Customer customer, ConnectorClient connector , Guid logId)
    {


        try
        {


        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            //defining accounts 
            var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: customer.name, id: customer.fromidstate);
            var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: botName, id: botId);

            //creating conversation
            var conversationId =  await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);


            message.From = botAccount;
            message.Recipient = userAccount;



            message.Text = "Daily Image";
            message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id.Replace("@", string.Empty));



            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageURL))
            {
                message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
                {
                    ContentUrl = imageURL,
                    ContentType = "image"
                });
            }




            await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);



        }).Wait();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        } 
    }
}

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Failed to fetch the file from the url","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":2018008,"fbtrace_id":"G8ZFKZLCmNp"}}
```

I am not sure what to do because when I am sending one message it's working fine but not all the 2200 messages isnt delivered , If i send it for 10 persons it's fine. and also the main problem is that the text gets delivered but not the image

Comment: I took the content type from the example in the url 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/image-attachment' , yes it's public image , this code is also working fine one sending for few users , it's just not working for thousand of users

Comment: The error being returned to you is being returned by the Facebook API.  Facebook generally returns this error when attachment is not a valid URL.  Are you certain that you are sending exactly the same thing to all users?

Comment: Yes , I solved the issue by slowing down the sending process , instead of creating 2200 threads , I create 10 threads every second , Although I am not sure that it shall be an issue but things are fine now

Answer (score 1):

The error is being returned by the Facebook API.  It looks like you are hitting a throttling limit.  The solution is to slow down the rate at which you send images.

You can check the error return code ("613") if you want to confirm

[Facebook error codes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#errors)